# How to insert Variable into PartiqL function within f-String

Tags: python

I want to insert a Variable into a PartiQL statement using an f-String. but somehow it fails.
the following does work:

```
 IndexName = 'GSI_1'    
 
 stmt = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}.{IndexName} WHERE SK=? AND begins_with(PK, 'READ#')"
```

the following does not work:

```
IndexName = 'GSI_1'     
Prefix = 'READ#'


stmt = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}.{IndexName} WHERE SK=? AND begins_with(PK, {Prefix})"
```

The variable "GSI_1" works perfectly fine, but the variable "Prefix" doesnt work since its inside the brackets of the Partiql function. Do I have to escape the second variable somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution; I was missing the single quotes: the proper code looks like this:

```
IndexName = 'GSI_1'     
Prefix = 'READ#'


stmt = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}.{IndexName} WHERE SK=? AND begins_with(PK, '{Prefix}')"
```